# How uprade css files from scss files with the ABP Template - ASP.NET MVC 5 (Module Zero - MPA - 3.6)?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

When I do some changes in the style.scss file of this Abp template, I do not find these changes in the associated style.css file.

I learned about grunt (which could play the combination and minification?) but I'm not comfortable because the basic examples do not quite fit with the abp template.

Could you tell me how to update the css files of the solution when scss files are modified?

The ABP Template is this one : ASP.NET MVC 5 v3.6 with Module Zero & MPA.
Source code is here: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/tree/master/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.WebMpa

Thanks!

Comment: you can use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu : Thank you, but unfortunately, after trying, I think this is not the tool used by the abp contributors in this template. The css (style.css) file generated by this WebCompiler extension adds bad entries. "@import url (..)" resilient.

Comment: The contributors use Gulp command. Run gulp